# Lotus Notes: How to create a view that displays only email in main folder and all it's subfolders?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have only one request. I want to crate a view that displays email from one main folder and all it's subfolders. Where I work we need to print all email correspondence by the end of the month for each contract that we manage and I have them all separated on each folder by contract number.

After creating a new View, using examples form google and here on Stackoverflow I tried the following but it doesn't work:

In Design Mode - Under View Selection:

SELECT FolderName = "K00001" : "K00001/Audits" : "K00001/Call Forwards" : "K00001/CAPs" : "K00001/CDR" : "K00001/DBA"

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to fix this, as this is not how folders work in Lotus Notes: It is not the document, that "knows" which folder it is in, but the folder that knows its contents. Selecting documents on base of the folder they are in is simply not possible.

There is a workaround, but I don't think, you will like it: You could enable folderreferences in the database properties of you mailfile. Unfortunately there is no frontend setting to do this, this has be done via Lotusscript:

```vb
Dim s As New notessession 
Dim db As notesdatabase 
Set db=s.CurrentDatabase 
If Not DB.FolderReferencesEnabled Then DB.FolderReferencesenabled=True
```

This code can be found in [this link at IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=463&uid=swg21092899).

After that every document that is moved to a folder gets a new item called "$FolderRef"

Attention: You need to move all documents to their folders again in order to fill the item in existing documents. The code for this is:

```vb
Dim db As NotesDatabase 
Dim col As Notesviewentrycollection 
Set db = s.CurrentDatabase 
If Not db.FolderReferencesEnabled Then
    db.FolderReferencesEnabled = True
End If 
Forall v In db.Views
    If v.isfolder Then
        Set col=v.AllEntries 
        Call col.PutAllInFolder(v.name)
    End If
End Forall
```

as can be found [in this second Link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21209890)

Unfortunately this item does NOT contain the name of the folder, but its unid. To make a view with all documents in certain folders would then be something like:

```vb
SELECT $FolderRef = "F649C931E:124AC559-NC1257D72:00481C00" : "F649C9AAA:124ACBBB-NC1257123:0048C999" : ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much Torsten, 

How about creating a view that displays only the emails that were sent to and received from select recipients or domain "gmail.com"?